# Momentjs - Week Numbers When April Is Week One

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using this function in momentjs I can find the week number of the year:

```
    var dt = new Date();
    var weekNumber = moment(dt).week();
```

Can anyone tell me how to set the first week in April as week one, and therefore for week 52 to be the last week in March.

In the documentation I can only see how to adjust the first day of the year (ie Sunday or Monday). I need to do both. Saturday will actually be day one.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add a custom function,

#### Sample

```js
function getCustomWeekNumber(weekNo) {
  var baseWeek = moment("01/04/", "DD/MM/").week() - 1; // 13
  var lastWeek = moment("31/12/", "DD/MM/").week() //53;
  return weekNo > baseWeek ? weekNo - baseWeek : (lastWeek - baseWeek) + weekNo;
}

var d = moment().week();
console.log(getCustomWeekNumber(d))

d = moment("01/04/2016", "DD/MM/YYYY").week();
console.log(getCustomWeekNumber(d))

d = moment("24/03/2016", "DD/MM/YYYY").week();
console.log(getCustomWeekNumber(d))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Will this work with leap years though? Because I noticed that leap years result in an extra week in a year.

Comment: @leroydev No. Any given year can only have 53 weeks. If you still wanna be sure, you can compute lastWeek. I'll update my answer

Comment: Another important change you should make to support leap years is letting the year for the first of April be generated instead of using "2016", as the leap day occurs on the 29th of Febuary (resulting in the first week of April being one week later in leap years).

Comment: @leroydev This is a sample. The optimizations that you are talking about should be done by you in your code.

Comment: @leroydev I have updated my answer. Also, 2016 is a leap year. So I guess this logic will work for all cases.